# Running custom functions with arguments from Chrome console

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, console, tampermonkey

I want to use Chrome console to run some JavaScript lines. I got this working thanks to tampermonkey, I have something like this that runs for any web:

```
window.req= function(){

    token = getToken()...
    link = "http://hello.com/"  + parameter + "/token=" + token;
    window.open(link);
    };
```

This is perfectly working, I'm able to get the info I need from the page and run `req()` on console.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm totally unable to send parameters. I do it by setting them before like this:

```
parameter = "thing"
req()
```

But is too ugly, I would like to do it like:

```
req("thing")
```

But I'm unable to make custom functions with parameters work on Chrome's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
window.getToken = function() { return "token12626"; }

window.req= function(parameter){
    token = getToken()
    link = "http://hello.com/"  + parameter + "/token=" + token;
    window.open(link);
    };

req("thing")
```